# Javascript post data and head to next page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a php page can check user's data, if data are correct, those data will pass to next page.

`if(data are correct){header("location:nextpage.php?data=...");}`

However I don't want those data to show on address bar. Since I can't use post here. Is possible to use javascript or Jquery to achieve this?

Comment: sessionStorage, localStorage, cookies, history api..all options

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using sessions instead?

If(data are correct), $_session[data]="value";